# Why does nothing show up under my views in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started a new rails project and followed a tutorial for that.

I created a scaffold:

```
rails g scaffold Book title:string author:string
```

and was supposed to now be able to see "books" under

```
/apps/views
```

but there is nothing but layouts. I kept following tutorial and did rake

db:migrate, started server, added books and everything that's supposed to show on the browser works, but I can't find anything under views. Now I had to create a controller and there is still nothing under views. In the prompt it even showed what was created and where

```
(/app/views).
```

I checked if I was in the right directory, I refreshed the folders, and now I am just frustrated... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Refreshed the folders"? How are you looking at the directories?

Comment: Normally you'll need both a layout and a view file. Do you have either of these in place? if not, create them.

Comment: did you check `/app/views` or `app/views`? Can you post the link to the tutorial you're following?

Comment: I am running Ruby on virtual box and using WinSCP to look at the files.

Comment: When I look at the directory under /root/project/app/views the only thing I see is the folder layouts

Comment: This is and the following videos is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=beqXhAO4UBc&index=1&list=PLgYiyoyNPrv-j6vFyXP8mgRyvpRqFkjb8

Comment: @KeTay are you positive that your migrations succeeded and that the scaffold was generated? You mentioned that you had to create some controllers. The scaffold will create a migration, a model, a controller, and a view. If you had to create ANY of those manually, your scaffold command did not work properly.

Comment: Thank you all! Jimi, yes everything was created. The controller was for something else. I eventually lost the connection and had to start WinSCP over and then everything showed up...